# How to log executed controller and action in node js?

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way in `node` or `express` to log which `controller` and which `action` gets executed when an `api` is called.

In `Ruby on rails` when an `api` is called `Rails` logs the executed `controller` and `action`. How to achieve it in `nodejs`

for example  in `Ruby on Rails`:

from `UI` I go to this url `localhost:3000/users/sign_in` in this case some `controller` will get executed below is what `rails` logs

`{"method":"GET","path":"/users/sign_in","format":"html","controller":"SessionsController","action":"new","status":200,"duration":167.26,"view":107.06,"db":39.51,"timestamp":"2019-03-07T17:41:51+05:30","request_id":null,"logged_in_user_token":null,"user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36","params":["controller","action"]}`

see here path: `/users/sign_in`

controller: `SessionsController`

action: `new`

is logged in logs

Comment: Please describe what are you trying to achieve exactly… Just please, don't post it in comments, instead update the question so we can assist you. You should also read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about express but I don't know of any built in way to do achieve this in node. If you build a server you would read the required parameters from your request object and then log them out manually after you send the proper response:

```
  if (statusCode == 200) {
console.log(
  "\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m",
  method.toUpperCase() + " /" + trimmedPath + " " + statusCode
);
  } else {
    console.log(
      "\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m",
      method.toUpperCase() + " /" + trimmedPath + " " + statusCode
    );
    console.log(payload);
  }
```

This will then get logged out to console every time you hit a route.